# Update Multiple Table Rows in Service from a list viewmodel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

I have a view model whose values ​​are sent as a list from the view for edit four input boxs ...

```
public class UpdatePollViewModel
{
    public List<string> Answer { get; set; }
}
```

In my service, I got the same values ​​from the database via Id:

```
public bool UpdatePoll(Guid id, UpdatePollViewModel viewModel)
{
    var polloption = _context.PollOptions.Where(p => p.PollId == Id).ToList();
}
```

I used this but it does not make sense because it repeats a lot!!!

```
 foreach (string item in viewModel.Answer)
 {
    foreach (var item2 in polloption)
    {
        item2.Answer = item;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Please note that the `[asp.net]` tag is for ASP.NET Framework, not for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish. This code looks like it's going to set all the `polloption` Answer to the last Answer. Also, very confusing when you don't pluralize your lists. `Answers` is much more readable.

Comment: @Steve Greene Obviously I have four inputs whose values ​​are taken from the database
Now I want to get the four values ​​that have a common ID and if it has changed, edit it in the database as well.

Comment: Obvious to you maybe. 4 input text boxes? I can only assume that each one is an Answer string? More info needed. Maybe start with the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the magic number is 4.

There are 4 input boxes that are used to populate the view model list with 4 answers in the same order as the existing 4 answers that are retrieved from the database and you want to map the 4 inputs to the 4 records from the database.

```
var polloption = _context.PollOptions.Where(p => p.PollId == Id).ToList();

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    polloption[i-1].Answer = viewModel.Answer[i-1];
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```